# get multiselect values for rallyfieldvaluecombobox using Rally SDK

Tags: rally

I want to get multiselect values from rallyfieldvaluecombobox. We can declare rallyfieldvaluecombobox to be multiselect with multiSelect: true but I am not sure how to read/get selected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use it just like any other combobox.

Get selected values:

```
combo.getValue();  // ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']
```

Set selected values:

```
combo.setValue(['Value1', 'Value2']);
```

I agree with you, the docs are probably not super clear on how to deal with multi-value.